# GROUP_CONTACT value use as a condition with other column

Tags: mysql, database

I have one case where I want to use group_contact value as a condition with other column.

please have a look the following code which I applied but return reference to group function.

take an one example as following.

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS loca_id,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(loc.total_qty)
        FROM
            locations_assign AS loc
        WHERE
            id IN (loca_id)) AS pend_qty
FROM
    locations_assign
WHERE
    putaway_type = 3
```

Is there any way where I can achieve this ?

Please help me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the IN clause you don't need a GROUP_CONCAT a SELECT sufficed

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS loca_id,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(loc.total_qty)
        FROM
            locations_assign AS loc
        WHERE
            id IN (SELECT 
                    id
                FROM
                    locations_assign
                WHERE
                    putaway_type = 3)) AS pend_qty
FROM
    locations_assign
WHERE
    putaway_type = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` returns a comma separated list of ids which is a string and can not be used with the operator `IN`.
 
Instead use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT 
  t.loca_id,
  SUM(loc.total_qty) AS pend_qty
FROM locations_assign AS loc
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS loca_id
  FROM locations_assign
  WHERE putaway_type = 3
) t
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(loc.id, t.loca_id)
```

Comment: A `CROSS JOIN` is a join without a join condition. What you are showing (join criteria hidden in the `WHERE` clause) is hence no cross join, but an `INNER JOIN (...) t ON FIND_IN_SET(loc.id, t.loca_id)`.

Comment: Sure but in cases like this where 2 datasets do not have an actual relationship like a foreign key that references a parent table and actually one of the datasets is just 1 row-1column I don't see it like an inner join.

Comment: But it is. You select the matches of two tables, as can be seen from the condition where something in one table is compared with something in the other. Inner joins are not only equi joins on some IDs; the tables can be related in many other ways. Using `CROSS JOIN` here is maybe even worse than using a comma-separated join, because it is pretending to join all possible combinations when it's not. (With a comma-separated join we'd at least expect we may find join criteria in the where clause.)

Comment: *it is pretending to join all possible combinations when it's not* it is not pretending. This is what it is doing. Every row of the table is joined to a single string/column and the WHERE clause filters out on a condition. This is what an INNER JOIN would do in this case if I used it with an ON clause. If your concern is efficiency then I don't disagree that a CROSS JOIN would do worse.

Comment: @forpas I just want data of selected loca_id in id IN (loca_id)) AS pend_qty. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`IN` doesn't work with a comma-separated strings, but with a list of separate values. As the list is just the IDs you are selecting anyway, it seems you only want a common aggregation: the list of IDs and the quantity sum:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS loca_id,
  SUM(total_qty) AS pend_qty
FROM locations_assign
WHERE putaway_type = 3;
```

Comment: This was my first thought, but it restricts the SUM to the rows where `putaway_type = 3`. The OP's code seems to SUM over all the ids retrieved by GROUP_CONCAT(). So this will work if id is the primary key (which is possible).

Comment: @forpas: `WHERE putaway_type = 3` is in the main query, so the resulting `GROUP_CONCAT`ID string only contains IDs of that type and then the subquery selects the rows of exactly those IDs again. But it may be that the example is just inappropriate and the OP wants to do something else really. If they can, they should avoid joining on a concat string; if they can't they should use `FIND_IN_SET` as you suggest.